# MySQL search column field string

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql column(name) with some text like this "firstname middlename surname lastname".
How can i select that row with a query like

```
SELECT name FROM client WHERE name like %firstname lastname%
```

. The where clause comes from a single html input text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it the way you asked, you could do it like this

```
SELECT name FROM client WHERE name LIKE 'John% %Doe'
```

So if in your table at the field "name" you have a value that is "John Fidzerald Mayhem Doe", it will be selected

But if I can advice you, create a column for each value you want, so a column for firstName which would not be nullable, a column for middlename which would be nullable, a column for surname which would be also nullable and a column for lastname which wouldn't be nullable

Comment: change **LIKE 'John% %Doe'** to **LIKE 'John% %Doe %'** to match surname

Comment: "firstname middlename surname lastname", surname is before lastName, so if i'm correct there is no use of "%" after Doe, since Doe is the lastName.

Comment: your search pattern dosent start with a %  and Doe starts with %. so its not garanted that Doe is a word. it can be also a piece of a string.  try this to see thats also match **SELECT "John test test Bigdoe" LIKE 'John% %Doe';**

Comment: Oh ok I get it, I was thinking in a way that 'Doe' is a definite and complete lastname. Of course if he want to search without a complete lastname, he can add % after Doe in this case. I understand what you meant now :D

Answer (score 1):

Could you use

```
select name from client where name like '%firstname%' and name like '%lastname%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search by separating the words in two where argumants

```
 SELECT name FROM client WHERE name like '%firstname%' AND  name like '%lastname%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The LIKE operator takes string parameters:  `string LIKE string`.

A string parameter can be a column name, in your case `name`.

Or it can be a string literal. String literals in MySQL are delimited by `'` quotation marks.  You didn't put them into your example, so it doesn't work. You want  `name like '%firstname lastname%'` for your query to work.

Or it can be an expression. That's a story for another day.